# Organizing a long prototype in node.js

Tags: node.js, file-structure

Been looking for a solution here but haven't found one since I started my project.  I'm hoping I'm just overlooking something.

I have lets say 50 methods on a certain prototype in my class.  Even though I separated them into sections it's still hard to find them by just scrolling.

I'm used to xCode with pragma marks.  Is there anyway to add section title headers in node.js?  And if so is there a quick way to get to them (on any ide, preferably cloud9 if you know).

I just want to rapidly see all my functions in a file and jump to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `require('./path/to/your/file')` as described here https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html:

```
var circle = require('./circle.js');
console.log( 'The area of a circle of radius 4 is ' + circle.area(4));
```

But you will need to organize your files to be modular, so you can `require` them in a meaningful way, for example each of your prototype functions/methods could be moved into its own js file which in turn could be `require`d and used to define the prototype etc.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for something a little more like what I'm used to (on xcode), but this will do.